# Orchard index with lucene is delayed

Tags: indexing, lucene, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have an index named Default in Orchard, alll is porperly configured o index some common parts and a part I have coded.

When I rebuild the index it always shows 0 documents indexed.

Non matter what I do I can hit update 100 times the index shows always 0 documents.

After some time (I cannot say exactly... after an hour or so) if I go to the index it is rebuilt with my 12567 documents.

Probably it is something by design but I do not get it...

My guess is that since the rebuilt of the index may be expensive in term or time and resources is scheduled at low priority and I have just wait the process.

Is there a way to force an immediate and complete rebuild?

The reason is that if I found a bug in my handler OnIndexing I have to wait an hour to see the effect of my fix...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indexing is a relatively heavy operation that is executed on a background thread. The class doing this is `IndexingBackgroundTask`, found in `Orchard.Indexing.Services`. The frequency at which background tasks are executed was, I think, recently raised in order to deal with scalability issues when there are hundreds of tenants on a single Orchard instance. This is configured in `Config/Sites.config`. Look for this bit of XML:

```
<component instance-scope="single-instance"
           type="Orchard.Tasks.SweepGenerator"
           service="Orchard.Tasks.ISweepGenerator">
    <properties>
        <property name="Interval" value="00:01:00" />
    </properties>
</component>
```

You can change the interval value to something smaller, if you understand the implications in the case where you have lots of tenants.

Comment: Great.... in my case I have just a big site but no tenants at all. I will try a smaller interval.

Comment: so the value="00:01:00" is 0days, 1hour, 0minutes?

Comment: No, and actually it's weird that you'd see an hour delay. The format of the config file is described here: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Xml-Configuration and the property values are deserialized using the standard .net deserialization logic. In this case, the Interval is a TimeSpan, for which the standard format is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx. So 00:01:00 actually is a minute.

Comment: However my component section is empty... just a commented settings for ISessionLocator. Anyway the default value in code for Interval in SweepGenerator is one minute as you say so the direction you pointed me is correct. Maybe a bug prevents schedule respecting this interval. No errors in log anyway, nor in debug log.

Comment: Yes, that's weird. Not sure where to look next.